# Spark Streaming and Cassandra - keeping data of previous insert in memory

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming process, which inserts data into Cassandra.

Results of each computational process will depend on the previous insert, so what I need to do is find a way to efficiently keep in memory only the data of the previous insert. Also, that in memory structures will be updated with each insert..

I considered using accumulator variables, but I will need too many values -> more than 5-6000.. Queering them every time from Cassandra is definitely not providing good performance.

What do you think I should do?

Comment: This question is pretty broad, but as a starting point check out [this](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter1/total.html) chapter from the Databricks reference application documentation. It gives an example of how to run calculations on streaming data which may not fit in memory on one machine.

Comment: Sounds like you should just be doing some windowing?

Comment: What is the source of your streaming job?

Comment: Thank you for the answers...

Source is Kafka..

Related to the windowing, I considered that, but time between two data arrivals can vary between, 1 min to 12 hours... 

Is there any option to keep some RDD in memory, and with each data load update it, flash it back to Cassandra (just in case), but also keep it cached..?